# Add multple maps to list in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have multiple maps (like 100 or more). I want to put them to list like this:

`ArrayList<HashMap> mapsList = new ArryaList(Arrays.asList(map1, map2, map3 ..., map100);`

is there a way to put all this in here in one loop to avoid writing the same name one hundred times changing only number in it?

**@EDIT**

I have this map like this:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("x", 47);
...
nextmap here...
```

Comment: You put the maps in 100 different variables? nope, one by one.

Comment: Is each map in its own variable?

Comment: I doubt you have a `Collection<Map>` somewhere, or you would not need to put then in your `ArrayList`, so you can't iterate variables that are not in some sort of collection

Comment: @AxelH usage of this is not important here, I need to put it like this

Comment: Your mistake is creating variables `map1`, `map2`, ... to begin with.

Comment: @khelwood why is that mistake?

Comment: it is not a problem of usage but a problem of what JAVA allow you to iterate to be able to loop on it ... you should not declare variables separatly if you want to iterate them, you declare them in a `Collection` directly.

Comment: @AxelH how to declare such structure to a Collection?

Comment: `list.add(new HashMap<>());` in a method with the values you need to insert in it if you need.

Comment: @soommy12 Because as individual variables, you cannot refer to them collectively. It would be less effort just to put them straight into a list and never have them in individual variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use a method to generate a map, insert the value and add it in the List.

```
public Map<String, Integer> newMap(Values... values){
    Map<String, integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(Values v : values){
        map.put(v.getKey(), v.getValue());
    }
    list.add(map);

    return map;
}
```

*Where `Values` hold both key and value*

```
class Values{
    String key;
    Integer value;

    public Values(String key, Integer value){
        ...
    }

    //getters;
}
```

That way, you don't need to play with `map1`, `map2`, `map3`, .. but simply call that method.

```
newMap(new Values("x", 47), new Values("y", 12));
newMap(new Values("x", 4));
```

...